# dont need call parameters in every rswag response block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails, rswag

```
parameter name: :search, in: :query, type: :string
```

I don't want pass search param in first response param, but accrued to an error at last
notice: if pass param with nil, in the controller is present as a string with zero length but still present? is true

```
 response('200', 'success') do
    run_test! { |_response| expect('length(address_books)').to match_json(3) }
 end

 response('200', 'search params') do
    let(:search) { 'aa' }
    run_test! { |_response| expect('length(address_books)').to match_json(2) }
  end
```

```
Failure/Error: super

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `search' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::***Controller:::Get::success:0x00007fa50f7de068>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `required: false` for your param:

```
parameter name: :search, in: :query, type: :string, required: false
```